# Number of core data objects with a defined attribute value

Tags: ios, core-data

I am using following fetch request to delete core data objects:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"entityName" inManagedObjectContext:context];
  NSFetchRequest *fetch=[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
  [fetch setEntity:entity];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(value1 == %@) AND (value2 == %@)", data1, data2];
 [fetch setPredicate:predicate];
  //... add sorts if you want them
  NSError *fetchError;
  NSArray *fetchedData=[self.moc executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&fetchError];
 for (NSManagedObject *product in fetchedProducts) {
    [context deleteObject:product];
  }
```

What I need is to execute the fetch request only if the number of objects in the core data entity with `[value1 isEqualToString: @"borrar"]` is greater than 1. How could I add this condition?

***EDIT
The attribute `value1` is a transient attribute.

Comment: Is "borrar" one of the values `data1` or `data2` that are already used in the predicate?

Comment: Yes, it is one of the values, but if countForFetchRequest counts the number of objects, I could change the predicate and consider only data2.

Comment: So you want to delete all objects with value1 == "borrar" and value == "someOtherString", but *only* if there are at least two objects with value1 == "borrar"?

Comment: @MartinR, value1 is a transient attribute. Sorry for not telling this before. I guess that is important to decide where to include the fetch request.

Comment: You *cannot* use a transient attribute in a Core Data fetch request. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check *how many* objects with a given attribute value exist, use `countForFetchRequest:`:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"entityName"];
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"value1 = %@", @"borrar"]];
NSError *error;
NSUInteger count = [self.moc countForFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (count == NSNotFound) {
    // some error occurred
} else if (count > 1) {
    // more the one object with "value1 == borrar"
}
```

*Update (according to the edited question):* You cannot use a transient attribute
in a Core Data fetch request. If "value1" is a transient attribute, you can only 
fetch all objects with "value2 == something", and then iterate over the fetched
array to check if there is more than one object with "value1 == borrar".

Comment: Thank you Martin, I will check your proposal, and I guess you are right as always. Thank you for your disponibility.

Comment: But the condition is important. Speaking in terms of table view, what I need is to delete one row from a section (transient attribute to sort the objects into sections) only if in that section are more than one object. In other words, on each section is a special row that should be deleted if there are more rows in the section. The row to be deleted has a value2 attribute which is different than the value2 attribute from the normal rows on its section.

Comment: Understood, but where in the code do you recommend to put this fetch request?

Comment: @mvasco: To check how many rows are in a section, you can call `NSInteger count = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section]` directly, perhaps that helps. - Otherwise you probably should update your question with more information about what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Then, for asking how many rows are in section 0, I can call NSInteger rowsInSection0 = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] but it is not working....

Comment: Martin, as you know I am using a transient attribute to sort the objects into sections. To avoid issues while adding or deleting objects, I have created a row on each section in order to always have one row on each section. Finally, the ultimate reason for the current question is to know how could I delete this extra row from a section when the user adds a real new row on the section. At the moment, and due that I can not fetch the entity for the transient attribute, I am only able to delete all extra rows created, not only the extra row from one section.

Comment: @mvasco: That was not obvious from your question :-) - I will think about it when I have more time ...

Comment: Martin, I have open a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21372904/deleting-core-data-objects-from-a-specific-section?noredirect=1#comment32232216_21372904

Answer (score 1):

```
NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(Value1 == borrar)"];
[fetch setPredicate:predicate];
NSError *fetchError;
NSArray *fetchedData=[self.moc executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&fetchError];
for(int i=0;i<fechedData.count;i++){
     [context deleteObject:[fechedData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"Value1"];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your proposal.But I guess you are not taken into account the main condition of my question. Where are you considering if the number of objects is >1 before deleting the objects? Sorry if I am wrong...

Comment: if([fechedData count]>0){//for loop statement(above)}

Comment: Thank you, I will also check your proposal.