# Deleting core data objects from a specific section

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

I have a very weird question, but if I can explain it well, I guess the answer will not be so difficult.
This is my current scenario:

I have a tableView with six fixed sections.

The sections are populated with core data objects.

I am using a transient attribute to decide on which section the object must be shown. This procedure is done in a NSManagedObject subclass. The transient attribute is called `sectionIdentifier`.

Due to the reason of using a transient attribute to decide on which section should appear every object, I decided to create a special row on each section, with the intention that there will be always at least one row on every section. This option will reduce the problem to have a nil section that would throw exceptions in case of adding or deleting rows, at least this has been a problem sometimes while testing the app.

That means that at the first launch every section has one row (I will call it the special row). And then the user can add/delete rows perfectly.

The problem I have now is that I need this special row to be remove if the section has new rows. At the same time, if the user deletes the last row in the section, the app automatically creates a new special row, so the section is never empty.

I know that this is not the best way to manage it, but due to my iOS knowledge, this is the best way I found to avoid exceptions while adding or removing rows from an empty section.

What I need is to delete the special row from a section when the user has added at least one new row to the section.

The object has a string  attribute called `quitar` and for the special rows: `quitar = @"si"`. This way, all special rows are easy to identify.

I am using this code to delete the special row if there are new rows in the section:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext;

NSEntityDescription *entity=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ToDoItem" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSFetchRequest *fetch=[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetch setEntity:entity];
NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"quitar like 'si'"];
[fetch setPredicate:predicate];
NSError *fetchError;
NSArray *fetchedData=[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&fetchError];
for (NSManagedObject *item in fetchedData){

                [context deleteObject:item];
            }
```

I was told that you cannot use transient attributes in a `NSPredicate`, and you can see in my code, that all special rows are deleted, not only the special from the desired section.
I need your help to find a way to delete only the special row from the section I want, not from all the sections.

Thank you and sorry for my english.

EDITED

Please find below the way I assign sectionIdentifier in the `NSManagedObject` class `ToDoItem`:

```
-(NSString *)sectionIdentifier{

    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];
    NSString *tmp = [self primitiveValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];




    if (!tmp){


        NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        NSInteger comps = (NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit);

        NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
        NSDate *date = self.todoDueDate;

        NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        [components setCalendar:calendar];
        [components setYear:2065];
        [components setMonth:11];
        [components setDay:12];

        NSDate *dateFuturoSomeday = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

        NSCalendar *calendar1 = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        NSDateComponents *components1 = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        [components1 setCalendar:calendar1];
        [components1 setYear:2065];
        [components1 setMonth:11];
        [components1 setDay:13];

        NSDate *dateFuturoCompleted = [calendar1 dateFromComponents:components1];




        NSDateComponents *date1Components = [calendar components:comps
                                                        fromDate: today];
        NSDateComponents *date2Components = [calendar components:comps
                                                        fromDate: date];
        NSDateComponents *date3Components = [calendar components:comps
                                                        fromDate: dateFuturoSomeday];
        NSDateComponents *date4Components = [calendar components:comps
                                                        fromDate: dateFuturoCompleted];


        today = [calendar dateFromComponents:date1Components];
        date = [calendar dateFromComponents:date2Components];
        dateFuturoSomeday = [calendar dateFromComponents:date3Components];
        dateFuturoCompleted = [calendar dateFromComponents:date4Components];



        NSInteger daysAfterToday = [calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit
                                               fromDate:today toDate:date options:0].day;
       // NSString *section;
        if (daysAfterToday < 0) {
            tmp  = @"0";
        } else if (daysAfterToday == 0) {
            tmp = @"1";
        } else if (daysAfterToday > 0 && daysAfterToday < 2) {
            tmp = @"2";
        }
        else if ([self.todoDueDate isEqualToDate:dateFuturoSomeday]){
            tmp = @"4";
        }
        else if ([self.todoDueDate isEqualToDate:dateFuturoCompleted]){
            tmp = @"5";
        }
        else {
            tmp = @"3";
        }






        [self setPrimitiveValue:tmp forKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];

    }


    return tmp;

}
```

Comment: how do you calculate your "sectionIdentifier", please share the code? can you change your "sectionIdentifier" to be persistent instead of transient?

Comment: I will put the code for the "sectionIdentifier" editing my question. I don't know if it is good to change it to persistent, I think there must be a reason to maintain it transient...

Comment: When you use a transient property as a "sectionNameKeyPath" all objects in the fetch must be faulted and calculate their section so the FRC could decide to which section they belong ==> very poor performance if many objects are present.

Comment: Yes, but this is the way to do it that I know. I am creating the app step by step, learning on each step, and it was very hard to make it working as it is working now. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: There were two reasons that I proposed a transient property in an answer to a previous question. 1) To keep the solution close to the "DateSectionTitles" sample code from Apple, which also uses a transient property. 2) Because the section is dependent on the *current date*. - Of course one can make the section identifier persistent if necessary. But then you have to re-calculate it when the day changes.

Comment: @MartinR, I am OK with the transient property, it works as I demanded and is having a good performance then the app should not manage hundreds of objetcs, but I need you to help me deleting the "special" row when needed. As it is I am deleting all "special" rows.

Comment: @MartinR, in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, if I used this NSString *itemSection = todoitem.sectionIdentifier I get the value of sectionIdentifier. May be, if I create another attribute (eg canBeDeleted), I could assign to this attribute a value. Then knowing the number of rows of a section, if it is > 1, then I could use the NSPredicate to sort for the object, no need to sort for sectionIdentifier. Do you think it will work?

Comment: @mvasco: Wouldn't it be better (and perhaps easier) to solve the problem with empty sections (instead of inserting and deleting dummy objects) ?

Comment: Yes, but with empty sections I am getting exceptions while adding and deleting objects. Thats why I created the dummy object

Comment: @mvasco: What I suggest is that you solve the *real* problem (the exceptions for empty sections) instead of solving the problems of your workaround.

Comment: @MartinR, thank you for your suggestion, but the problem is that I am not able to do it, I detected the problem when I implemented the expanded and collapsed sections. I don't feel to be able to redo everything now. If you could clean my code, I could try as you suggest, but if you cannot help me, I will try the workaround. Thank you in any case.

Comment: @MartinR, I have it, and it is working as expected. Should I put it as an answer to my question?

Comment: Yes of course. If you solved the problem then you can answer your own question.

Comment: @MartinR, I have answered my own question. If you have time, I would appreciate any comment about it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked that at the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, I am able to detect the value from the transient attribute `sectionIdentifier`. That means that I can use it to identify the special row item, update the value of another attribute an delete it.

```
 ToDoItem *todoitem = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        NSString *sec = todoitem.sectionIdentifier;
        NSString *quitar = todoitem.quitar;


        if ([sec isEqualToString:@"1"] && [quitar isEqualToString:@"si" ] && ( numObjectsSec1 > 1 ) ){
            NSLog(@"DAS OBJEKT KANN GELÖSCHT WERDEN  %@", todoitem.todoName);

            NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext;
            [todoitem setValue:@"si se puede borrar" forKey:@"borrar" ];
             NSError *error = nil;
             // Save the object to persistent store
             if (![context save:&error]) {


                 [context deleteObject: todoitem];



             };
```